# Did Peirce apply his triadic theory to music?

Tags: peirce, semiotics, music

Did Peirce apply his [triadic](http://www.commens.org/dictionary/term/triad) theory (that things are comprised of [Firstness](http://www.commens.org/dictionary/term/firstness), [Secondness](http://www.commens.org/dictionary/term/secondness), [Thirdness](http://www.commens.org/dictionary/term/thirdness)) to music?

Comment: No, but others tried, see e.g. [Turino](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5406/ethnomusicology.58.2.0185)

Comment: @Conifold Maybe you can turn your comment into a full answer.

Comment: Not really. There is nothing to say about Peirce, and I am not well versed in the work of later semioticians on music to usefully summarize it.

Comment: @Conifold Did Peirce write anything on music theory?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Semioticians are drawing on his general theory of signs, which covers musical signs, but he did not discuss those specifically.